# Why rectus abdominis is not proximal muscle?

Tags: muscles, anatomy

I am thinking this picture which shows proximal muscles.

[image]

**Why for instance pectoralis major, subclavius and rectus abdominalis are not included in proximal muscles?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what "proximal" means in this context. It's not a standard use of that anatomical term in English. I'd also say that the figure on the left actually does show the pectoralis major.

The author of this figure might be trying to show the muscles that cross the proximal joints in the upper and lower limbs. For example:

Upper limb

- Pectoralis major
- Biceps brachii
- Triceps brachii
- Latissimus dorsi

Lower limb

- Adductors (brevis, longus, magnus)
- Rectus femoris
- Semimembranosus, semitendinosus, biceps femoris (long head)
- Gluteals (maximus, medius, minimus)

Muscles that do not cross the shoulder or hip are not included. This explains the lack of rectus abdominis or subclavius. Though it is not clear to me which the paired muscles in the posterior view are running craniocaudally from the thorax to the gluteal region.